# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) test_helper.rb

Tags: ruby, devise, capybara, warden, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Ruby and needed some assistance figuring something out:  I've been stuck on this error for 2 days.  I know if I figure out the connect issue everything is going to work perfectly.  Please help.

#test_helper.rb

```
$LOAD_PATH<< File.expand_path(__FILE__)
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
Rails.env='test'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'action_view/test_case'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'factories'

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  include Devise::TestHelpers


end

class  ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    DatabaseCleaner.start  
  end

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
  end
end


class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  Warden.test_mode!
  # Stop ActiveRecord from wrapping tests in transactions
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
    Capybara.reset_sessions!    # Forget the (simulated) browser state
    Capybara.use_default_driver # Revert Capybara.current_driver to Capybara.default_driver
  end

end

class ActionController::TestCase
  # include Devise::TestHelpers
end

require 'selenium-webdriver'
module ::Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox
  class Bridge
    attr_accessor :speed

    def execute(*args)
      result = raw_execute(*args)['value']
      case speed
        when :slow
          sleep 0.3
        when :medium
          sleep 0.1
      end
      result
    end
  end
end

def set_speed(speed)
  begin
    page.driver.browser.send(:bridge).speed=speed
  rescue
  end
end
```

#test/unit/project_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  setup do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @company = FactoryGirl.create(:company, :name=>'MegaTesters')
    @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, :name=>'testProject', :budget=>100000)
    assert @project.valid?
    @sow = @project.contracts.create :name=>"first", :company=>@company, :type=>"Sow"
    @invoice = @sow.invoices.create :amount=>25000
    @payment = @invoice.payments.create :amount=>10000

  end

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
  end

  test "remaining funds" do

  end
end
```

#STACK TRACE:

```
bundle exec rake test:units TEST=test/unit/project_test.rb --trace
(in /Users/higgs001/Sandbox/att-innovate/foundry_ledger)
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "assignments_id_seq" for serial column "assignments.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "assignments_pkey" for table "assignments"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "attachments_id_seq" for serial column "attachments.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "attachments_pkey" for table "attachments"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "companies_id_seq" for serial column "companies.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "companies_pkey" for table "companies"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "contracts_id_seq" for serial column "contracts.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "contracts_pkey" for table "contracts"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "fundings_id_seq" for serial column "fundings.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "fundings_pkey" for table "fundings"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "invoices_id_seq" for serial column "invoices.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "invoices_pkey" for table "invoices"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "lockers_id_seq" for serial column "lockers.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "lockers_pkey" for table "lockers"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "pages_id_seq" for serial column "pages.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pages_pkey" for table "pages"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "payments_id_seq" for serial column "payments.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "payments_pkey" for table "payments"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "projects_id_seq" for serial column "projects.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "projects_pkey" for table "projects"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "queue_classic_jobs_id_seq" for serial column "queue_classic_jobs.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "queue_classic_jobs_pkey" for table "queue_classic_jobs"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "versions_id_seq" for serial column "versions.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "versions_pkey" for table "versions"
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
Run options: --seed 14051

# Running tests:

E

Finished tests in 0.802822s, 1.2456 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_remaining_funds(ProjectTest):
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/http/client.rb:19:in `post'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/index.rb:80:in `store'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/model/search.rb:134:in `block in update_index'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2302947893627650000__update_elasticsearch_index__985824136385614657__callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_update_elasticsearch_index_callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/model/search.rb:130:in `update_index'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tire-0.4.2/lib/tire/model/callbacks.rb:21:in `block in included'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:471:in `_run__2302947893627650000__save__985824136385614657__callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:104:in `save!'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `[]'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/factory_girl-3.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
    /Users/higgs001/Sandbox/att-innovate/foundry_ledger/test/unit/project_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:ProjectTest>'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__3361187329649106861__setup__985824136385614657__callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p32...]
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:60:in `verbose'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:98:in `block in define'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/higgs001/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:units
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ElasticSearch needs to be configured.  Special thanks to Lee Hambley.

Comment: This helped me. does this mean i have an "L" on my forehead L:/

Answer (score 1):

It's a little general answer. When I faced the same error, it was because localhost has no SMTP server. RSpec is just displaying `Errno::ECONNREFUSED:                                                                                                     Connection refused - Connection refused` on the line of FactoryGirl.create(:user) it's a little confusing but adding `--backtrace` when run `rspec` helps to figure out what exactly happens.